# vba click on hyperlink on website

Tags: html, vba

Hi I am trying to click on a hyperlink on a webpage: https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/community_facts.xhtml

I want to click on the link:

> 2016 American Community Survey
>
> **Demographic and Housing Estimates (Age, Sex, Race, Households and Housing, ...)**

I have tried

```
   'start a new subroutine called SearchBot
    Sub SearchBot()

'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
Dim y As Integer 'integer variable we'll use as a counter
Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link
Dim Link As Object
Dim ElementCol As Object

'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
objIE.Visible = True

'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
objIE.navigate "https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/community_facts.xhtml"

'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
While objIE.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend

'in the search box put cell "A2" value
objIE.document.getElementById("cfsearchtextbox").Value = _
  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value

'click the 'Add/Remove Geographies' button
objIE.document.getElementById("communityfactssubmit").Click

'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
While objIE.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend

 
    Set ElementCol = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each Link In ElementCol
    If Link.innerHTML = "Demographic and Housing Estimates (Age, Sex, Race,Households and Housing, ...)" Then
        Link.Click
    End If
    Next Link
```

It doesn't work. But I can click on link such as "Feedback", "FAQs" using this method. Please help. Thank you!!!

Here is the path to the link, I don't know if I can just use this to grab the link instead of trying to locate the text

## cf-content > div:nth-child(2) > div.links > ul:nth-child(4) > li > div > a

Comment: Try `If Link.innerText Like "Demographic and Housing*" Then`

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work...

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code where you're loading the page?  If you put a break on the line `Link.Click` does it even get there?

Comment: Please see my entire code , everything works untill this clicking link action

Comment: What search value are you entering?

Comment: Any city would work. I have "Draper City" in my cell A2

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: the page is not fully loaded when you populate the links collection, so you need to add a short wait just before that.

```
Sub SearchBot()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim aEle As Object 'HTMLLinkElement
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim result As String
    Dim Link As Object
    Dim ElementCol As Object

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate "https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/community_facts.xhtml"

    WaitFor objIE

    objIE.document.getElementById("cfsearchtextbox").Value = "Draper City"
    objIE.document.getElementById("communityfactssubmit").Click

    WaitFor objIE
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2) '<<<<<< wait 2 sec

    Set ElementCol = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each Link In ElementCol
        Debug.Print Link.innerText
        If Link.innerText Like "Demographic and Housing Estimates*" Then
            Link.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Link

End Sub

'utility Sub: wait for page to load
Sub WaitFor(IE As Object)
    While IE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: OMG I spend so many hours on this... I cannot thank you more!!! Thank you!!